# How to traverse the outermost hash table in freemarker FTL

Tags: freemarker

The map in JAVA CODE

```
Map dataMap = new HashMap();
dataMap.("key1","value1");
dataMap.("key2","value2");
dataMap.("key3","value3");
dataMap.("key4","value4");
```

and freemarker

```
template.process(dataMap, out);
```

In the FTL

```
<#list dataMap.keySet() as k>
  <span>${k}:</span><span>dataMap[k]</span>
</#list>
```

I got the error:
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression dataMapis undefined

So how can I get the value of "key1","key2","key3" and "value1","value2","value3" in the FTL?
I tried to use "rootMap",".main",".vars" to replace "dataMap".All invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.dataModel` special variable like this:

```
<#list .data_model?keys as prop>
    ${prop} - ${.data_model[prop]}
</#list>
```

See the [freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html).